# How to download XAP file to Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

How can I download a XAP file to Windows Phone 7?

> "Can't download file Windows Phone doesn't support this file type."

Comment: You can refer the below tutorials.. http://thewp7phones.com/install-xap-files-on-windows-phone-7/ http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/install-xap-files-on-your-windows-phone-7-device-how-to-guide/ It may help you...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Start -> All programs -> Windows Phone Developer Tools -> Application Deployment. This tool allows you to choose a XAP file and deploy it on your developer unlocked phone.

Answer (score 0):

only full (or using WP7RootTools) unlocking the device and using a XapDeployer app.

you can find all informations here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1555862

If you want to install it, use the "Application Deployment" applications installed with the SDK